# how to create Dynamic Popup With different Contents

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

i am creating a Grid where each row is different.the last  td of each row is

```
  <a href="view_all" > View All</a>
```

now when its clicked so i want to show a popup and its contents will be same as this row.

```
 <?php
$sr_no = 1;

foreach($this->paginator as $record){
    if($sr_no % 2 == 0)
        $style = 'class="even-row"';
      else
        $style = 'class="odd-row"';
        ?>  
                    <tr <?php echo $style;?>>
                            <td class="sorting_1"> <input type="checkbox" /> </td>
                            <td><?php echo $record['contact_first_name'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $record['contact_mobile_no'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $record['contact_home_no'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $record['contact_office_no'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $record['contact_email'];?></td>
                            <td><a id="view_all" href="" > View All</a></td>
                    </tr>
                   <?php $sr_no ++; }?>
```

in my java script
i want to applay this on each

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#view_all").click(function(){
      //i want dialouge but all the contents of that row
        // $("#view_all").dialog();
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the above code is working great than just replace your this line

```
$('.view_all').click(function(){
```

with

```
$('.view_all').on('click',function(){
```

and your problem is solved

Comment: `.live()` was deprecated, just as an FYI. You should now be using `.on()`

Comment: Thanks Brad this ll work $('.view_all').on('click',function(){

Answer (score 2):

First off, you won't be able to use `view_all` as a name if there are multiple rows. You could make it a class name, but an ID must be unique on the page. So I recommend something like this:

```
<a href="" class="view_all"> View All</a>
```

Then, you can bind to the class, pull the details from the row and push it to a dialog, then display it, like so:

```
// bind to the link's click event
$('.view_all').click(function(){

  // find the row
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

  // grab the information (I don't know of another way other than use
  // column position. However, if you add classes or some other details
  // to the rows as their being output, this would be easier.
  var contact_first_name = $tr.children('td:eq(1)').text(),
      contact_mobile_no = $tr.children('td:eq(2)').text(),
      contact_home_no = $tr.children('td:eq(3)').text(),
      contact_office_no = $tr.children('td:eq(4)').text(),
      contact_email = $tr.children('td:eq(5)').text();

  // build the dialog
  var $dialog = $('<div>',{title:'Details'}).dialog({
    autoOpen: false
    // ...more dialog options...
  });

  // add details to dialog:
  $('<p>').text('First Name: ' + contact_first_name).appendTo($dialog);
  $('<p>').text('Mobile #: ' + contact_mobile_no).appendTo($dialog);
  /* ... */

  // show the dialog
  $dialog.dialog('open');
});
```

Working demo can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJVcm/1/

Comment: sir ! everything is working i mean every value i alert is accessing but the dialouge is not showing at end.and no error in console too

Comment: @ShreyaGhoshal: Did you remove the `// ...more dialog options...` and replace it with your own options? (And you can't just remove it because of the common on the line above it, so you'd need to remove that comma too)

Comment: certainly i removed it.and have not add my options i just need that popup.is there any thing to include for this to work ??

Comment: @ShreyaGhoshal: jQuery & jQuery-UI (with style sheet) should be included. I assumed you already included these given the tags you used in your question.

Comment: i have include these <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: also this <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('/assets/scripts/jqueryui/jqueryui.css'); ?> " type="text/css" media="screen" />

Comment: @ShreyaGhoshal: My apologies, i was calling `.dialog('show')~ when it should have been `.dialog('open')`. I've fixed the code in my answer, try that.

Comment: i have pagination too here the script not working in another page.the pagination is through ajax

Comment: use `$('.view_all').on('click',function(){` to it binds to present (and future) elements matching the selector.

Comment: i am sorry sir i am not getting it if you please explain it i ll be grateful to you.Thanking you in aniticipation

Comment: @ShreyaGhoshal: Basically, using `.click(...)` attaches the click event to elements on the page currently. By using `.on('click',...)` you can match not only elements on the page but elements added later on (e.g. your pagination that fetches new items with ajax)